# Extracting element with specific type from string with generic lambda

Tags: c++, c++14, generic-lambda

I am using c++. I have string which can contains element start with `^` and end with `$`.  This element can be `int` or `string`.

**Example:**

```
"....^15$asdasd"-> 15
"...^bbbb$ccc"->"bbbb"
```

I would like to write lambda function which would do this.
If I use template function the code would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
T getElem(string S)
{
     T retElem;
     // make calculations
     // ....
     return retElem;
}
```

but when I try using generic lambda I am reaching this situation :

```
auto getElem = [] () {
     T retElem;
     // make calculations
     // ....
     return retElem;
};
```

the problem is how to get type of retElem. Is there a way to use lambda in this case. I want to use generic lambda in function, where such such extraction is used. I want to to encapsulate this logic only in the function.

Comment: Why do you want to use a lambda? What's wrong with the function template you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic lambdas have to have the argument of a (templated) type, you can't have generic lambda templatized on a non-argument. The easiest way to solve your problem is to provide a dummy argument of a given type. As in:

```
template<class T>
struct identity { using type = T; };
...
auto lam = [](auto the_type) {
    using T = typename decltype(the_type)::type;
    ...
};
...
lam(identity<T>{});
...
```

Comment: SergayA this is good suggestion.  My purpose is to use lambda in a function where such code is repeated. I will fix this in my question. Your suggestion is OK if "struct identity" is in namespace scope. plus 1

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev yes, identity has to be in namespace scope, for obvious reasons. On any rate, this is very valueable tool for anybody doing serious metaprogramming :D

Answer (score -3):

Since it is C++14, you can use compiler type inference through `decltype(auto)`:

```
int i = []() -> decltype(auto) {
    return 1;
}();
```

Comment: I was asking for for deduction of type of retElem not for returning type. Maybe I understand sth wrong.  Could you write more details.

Comment: Not an answer to the question as asked.